# How do you make a license for your programs?

Tags: c#, windows, licensing

As the title says "How do you make a license for your programs?"
Do you use a plugin or do you make your own? I've looked the whole day for finding resulutions, but didnt found one yet.
I basically want a normal license for my program:
A textbox where you type your license *"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"* 
Is it possible to make this yourself, or should i use a website for it? If i should use a website, which do you recomend then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is rather simple to implement a simple license yourself **BUT** it will no be very save.

Because C# is transformed into IL, everybody can decompile your code easily and work around your license checks. It is very hard to build a license mechanism in a save way, so you should resort to some existing, proven solution.